# Installing Windows Service fails

Tags: .net, windows-services, installutil

I'm trying to install a .NET 4 Windows Service on a production server: Running InstallUtil.exe gives me this error message:

> Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
>   System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///D:\myservice.exe'
>   or one of its dependencies. This
>   assembly is built by a runtime newer
>   than the currently loaded runtime and
>   cannot be loaded..

Obviously, it's complaining about the service being written in .NET 4. But the framework is correctly installed on the server as I have other .NET 4 apps running. This is the first time I'm trying to install a *service*.

I did a bit of googling, and have tried setting the "Target CPU" to "AnyCPU" under Advanced Compiler Settings. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have a bitness mismatch.  If this is a 64-bit server, then there's probably a 32-bit DLL somewhere that has the same name as the 64-bit DLL the program is trying to load.  Or, on a 32-bit server, there's a 64-bit DLL somewhere.

I've found that when this happens, the application error log (Windows command `eventvwr`) will tell me where the offending DLL is).

Comment: Got it now: I'd grabbed the wrong InstallUtil.exe (non-.NET 4) from my workstation and deployed it together with my service. D'oh.